# Output won't format correctly. Creates Random Indents

Tags: c++14

I am new to C++ and programming.

I am using the CLion editor. I created a simple program for a homework assignment and I can't figure out why my out put indents every line after the second line. I have searched online and here, but most indent questions ask how to indent, not how to make your output stop indenting when I never asked it to.

Thanks in advance for any help. I appreciate it.

I tried using code to left align, but that didn't work. I also tried creating a new project and retyping it in. I still got the same result.

I also tried adding a new line break--that prevents the indent, but then I have a blank line.

I think it may be a setting---but I have no idea which setting to change.
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int numberPennies, numberNickels, numberDimes, numberQuarters, 
    totalCents;

    cout << "Please Enter Number of Coins:  " << endl;
    cout << "# of Quarters: ";
    cin >> numberQuarters;
    cout << "# of Dimes: ";
    cin >> numberDimes;
    cout << "# of Nickels:  ";
    cin >> numberNickels;
    cout << "# of Pennies:  ";
    cin >> numberPennies;

    totalCents = int((numberQuarters * 25) + (numberDimes * 10) + 
    (numberNickels * 5) + (numberPennies));

    cout << "The total is " << int(totalCents / 100) << " dollars and " 
    << int(totalCents % 100) << " cents ";

return 0;}`
```

The result should be left aligned, instead my output appears like this:

```
`Please Enter Number of Coins:
# of Quarters:13
 # of Dimes:4
   # of Nickels:11
     # of Pennies:17
   The total is 4 dollars and 37 cents
Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the default *Code Style* for **CLion**. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, go to `Editor | Code Style` and open the page of your programming language.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and I changed the Code style to C++, but that didn't change the output.

Comment: I guess I must have misunderstood your problem. Have you tried using `std::left` as specified in the reference [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're doing everything right, I ran this code in Visual Studio 2019 and didn't have the issue you're describing. I think that the indentation you're seeing might be a feature of your IDE.
Try running the .exe you're generating instead of using the built in console in your IDE.

[image: It works fine]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was thinking it must be some type of setting.

What do you mean by running the exe?

Comment: Thank you for testing it, it's nice to know it works.

I ran the exe as you suggested, and it also worked, but I have to hand in a .cpp file. for my assignment, so somehow I have to fix it there, right?